# Is Prefect's VertexRun a GCP or AWS solution?

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, prefect

In Prefect's documentation, under the definition of [vertex run](https://docs-v1.prefect.io/api/latest/run_configs.html#vertexrun) the example definition was for Google's "[e2-standard-4](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/general-purpose-machines)".

However, it says there that the spec should be [workerPoolSpec](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ecs.html#ECS.Client.register_task_definition) linking to the AWS documentation. (And so are the links to [machine_types](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/userguide/task-cpu-memory-error.html) and [CustomJobSpec](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ecs.html#ECS.Client.register_task_definition))

Is this a solution for GCP or AWS? Which is the mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The document is intended as a GCP solution but unfortunately the links are mixed up, redirecting to AWS pages.

Notice at the bottom part of the Prefect's VertexRun documentation, there are the correct links for the GCP documents, however the hyperlinked numbers point to AWS as well.

- [CustomJobSpec](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/reference/rest/v1/CustomJobSpec)
- [Machine types](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/training/configure-compute#machine-types)

You'll find the [WorkerPoolSpec](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/reference/rest/v1/CustomJobSpec#workerpoolspec) as part of the CustomJobSpec document.